# Wordpress: why is one of my users unable to edit other author's posts?

Tags: wordpress, edit, user-permissions

I have a wordpress website with several different authors and two admins, of which I am one.  I have attempted to promote one of my authors to an editor and then an admin so she can edit other authors posts.  But it isn't working.  She can edit her own posts, but when she goes to edit somebody else's post she can't change anything, preview button is disabled.

I and the other admin are able to edit others posts with no problems.

What do I need to do to allow my new editor to edit posts from other authors?

Edit:  I should mention that I tried the User Role Editor plugin to see if that would improve things, but it says my editor user should have the right permissions to preview, save and publish other people's posts.

Edit: Another thing I should have mentioned is that I installed the 'Hide My WP' plugin to block hackers -- and that appears to be the source of my problems.  I put details into my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem so I figured I'd share it here for future sufferers.  It turns out that the security on my 'Hide my WP' plugin was turned up too high, I turned off the IDS firewall for frontend+backend and made it 'frontend' only.  Voila, all of my users are able to edit posts again!

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress summary of roles:

- Super Admin – somebody with access to the site network administration features and all other features. See the Create a Network article.
  Administrator – somebody who has access to all the administration features within a single site.
- Editor – somebody who can publish and manage posts including the posts of other users.
- Author – somebody who can publish and manage their own posts.
- Contributor – somebody who can write and manage their own posts but cannot publish them.
- Subscriber – somebody who can only manage their profile.

Adding special role.
First make sure you are using a child theme. In your function.php file put this piece of code.

```
//Add a custom user role
$result = add_role('userx', __('UserX'),
 array(
 'read' => true,
 'edit_posts' => true,
 'edit_pages' => true,
 'edit_others_posts' => true,
 'create_posts' => true,
 'manage_categories' => true,
 'publish_posts' => true,
 'edit_themes' => false,
 'install_plugins' => false,
 'update_plugin' => false,
 'update_core' => false
)
);
```

Note: If permission aren't working,  It's maybe because the codes that handle permissions are modified. To make it easier and solve the problem, look for a plugin like `User Role Editor` and install it.

Comment: I actually have tried User Role Editor but it didn't help at all. Is there any other reason the permission doesn't work right?

Comment: There' a bunch of plugin available you may also try to use https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/

Comment: I just downloaded it so I assume it is updated!  I'll give the role-scoper a try as well.